# Android Scrolling Autogrow Listview

Tags: android

Hello I've been trying to adapt a never ending listview to use JSON data instead of just a array, I know the code to connect to the server and pull back data works as I've tested it on its own, but inside this piece of code I get a UnknownhostException, does anyone have any idea what is wrong...thnaks..

```
public class NeverEndingList extends ListActivity {


//how many to load on reaching the bottom
int itemsPerPage = 15;
boolean loadingMore = false;    
int rowsSTART = 0;
int rowsEND = itemsPerPage;
ArrayList<String> myListItems;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//For test data :-)
Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);



    //This will hold the new items
    myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myListItems);




    //add the footer before adding the adapter, else the footer will nod load!
    View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
    this.getListView().addFooterView(footerView);

    //Set the adapter
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    //Here is where the magic happens
    this.getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

        //useless here, skip!
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

        //dumdumdum         
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


            //what is the bottom iten that is visible
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;             

            //is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load more !
            if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){                 
                Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                thread.start();
            }
        }
    });



    //Load the first 15 items
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
    thread.start();

}


//Runnable to load the items

private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {
    JSONArray jArray=null;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Set flag so we cant load new items 2 at the same time
        loadingMore = true;
        //Reset the array that holds the new items
        myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Simulate a delay, delete this on a production environment!
        try { Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

         try
         {
         new Thread(new Runnable()
         { 
             public void run()
                { 
                    Looper.prepare(); 
            int xx=0;
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
            //params.put("X", String.valueOf(rowsSTART));
            //params.put("Y", String.valueOf(rowsEND));
            params.put("X", "10");
            params.put("Y", "5");

            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            // loop round dynamic array of parameters
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            Iterator<String> it = params.keySet().iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) 
            {
                String key=(String)it.next();
                String value=(String)params.get(key);
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key,value));
            }

            try{

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.phoneinternational.biz/proccityLimit.php");                    
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                //InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                is = entity.getContent();
          }catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "X1:: "+e.toString());
             // if (DEBUG_LOG) { Log.e("log_tag", "ProcessHTTPRequest:Error in http connection "+e.toString()); }
          }
          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HERE2", 10).show();


          //convert response to string
          try{
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                       sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
          }catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "X2:: "+e.toString());
            //  if (DEBUG_LOG) { Log.e("log_tag", "ProcessHTTPRequest:Error converting result "+e.toString()); }
          }

          try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                   JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   myListItems.add(json_data.getString("city"));
            }
          }
          catch (Exception e) {Log.e("log_tag", "X3:: "+e.toString()); }
        //  return(null);
            }
   //           catch(Exception e) { } 
                //  Looper.loop(); 


           //            }

                 }).start();
                }
    //      }
                catch (Exception e) { 
                    Log.e("log_tag", "X3:: "+e.toString());
               //     if (DEBUG_LOG) { Log.e("WorldDialer:loadData",e.getMessage(),e); }
                }

                //Done! now continue on the UI thread
    try {

    }
    catch (Exception e) {Log.e("log_tag", "X3:: "+e.toString()); }
    //  return(null);
     runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }

};  


//Since we cant update our UI from a thread this Runnable takes care of that! 
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {         
        rowsSTART = rowsEND;

        //Loop thru the new items and add them to the adapter
        if(myListItems != null && myListItems.size() > 0){
            for(int i=0;i<myListItems.size();i++)
                adapter.add(myListItems.get(i));
        }

        //Update the Application title
        rowsEND += itemsPerPage;

        setTitle(" List  start: " + String.valueOf(rowsSTART) + " items  END:" + String.valueOf(rowsEND));

        //Tell to the adapter that changes have been made, this will cause the list to refresh
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //Done loading more.
        loadingMore = false;
    }

};




//
// connect to webserver and retrieve data
//
public String loadData(String URL, Map<String, String> params)
{
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    // loop round dynamic array of parameters
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    Iterator<String> it = params.keySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) 
    {
        String key=(String)it.next();
        String value=(String)params.get(key);
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key,value));
    }


    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        is = entity.getContent();
  }catch(Exception e){
     // if (DEBUG_LOG) { Log.e("log_tag", "ProcessHTTPRequest:Error in http connection "+e.toString()); }
  }



  //convert response to string
  try{
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),line,10).show();
               sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
  }catch(Exception e){
    //  if (DEBUG_LOG) { Log.e("log_tag", "ProcessHTTPRequest:Error converting result "+e.toString()); }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use handlers ok

you make the thread running when evrything is finished you jus call the hadler that will update the UI

in your case if you plase a call to hadler on the runnable `loadMoreListItems`

> to call the hendler use these:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

> the handler

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
//af is your adpater these makes update to the UI :D
af.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Hello subspider thanks for the reply could you give me a bit more detail of how to do this. Really what i am trying to do is something like this: http://androidboss.com/load-listview-in-background-asynctask/  but all the examples seem to use a predefined array of x items, but this defeats the object of what I am trying to do, I don't know how many items there are they are coming from the web?? Thanks Ian